# Linq query for my List<Square> to see if an item of one list is in another

Tags: c#, linq

I've tried multiple lines of code from related questions but they didn't seem to work for me.

I have two `List<Square>`s:

```
List<Square> List1 = new List<Square> { sq1, sq2, sq3 };
List<Square> List2 = new List<Square> { sq1, sq5, sq7 };
```

I wanna remove all squares from `List2` that are in `List1` already. I tried this code for example:

```
var test2NotInTest1 = List1.Where(l1 => !List2.Any(l2 => l1.Contains(List2)));
```

from a related question but it didn't work at all. I'm still a newbie with this so I might've just typed it wrong. I hope you can help me out!

Comment: show us your square object

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't this work for you?

```
var test2NotInTest1 = List2.Except(List1);
```

If `Square` is a `class` (not a `struct`) and the list elements point to the same variables, this should work. Otherwise you'll need to implement [`IEquatable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.100).aspx) on your `Square` class/struct (or at the very least, provide correct `GetHashCode` and `Equals` functions).

Comment: Thank you! it is a class indeed, I hope this will fix it.

Comment: @Noomie did this work for you? If so, please mark the answer as accepted so that others will know the solution worked. Otherwise, if it didn't work, please expand on what problems did you encounter so we can help further

Comment: Nope, it didn't work :( It doesn't give me any errors whatsoever, but it doesn't remove the squares that should be removed either. I'm not sure what the problem could be :(

Comment: What result are you expecting? I just tried it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Qj3ha0 and it gives the correct result according to your specification: `"I wanna remove all squares from List2 that are in List1 already"`, so it takes `List2` and removes `sq1` which is in `List1`, and leaves `sq5` and `sq7`, which are not. Is your question correct?

Answer (score 2):

Use RemoveAll method.

```
List2.RemoveAll(x=>List1.Contains(x));
```

Or if you want to remove squares with the same dimensions you can use following

```
List2.RemoveAll(x => List1.Any (y=> x.x == y.x && x.y == y.y && x.width == y.width && x.height == y.height));
```

Comment: I think object is not compare directly in contains method, you should use Implement IEquatable interace on square class and specify a property to compare..

Comment: @ITGenius `List<Square> List1 = new List<Square> { sq1, sq2, sq3 };
List<Square> List2 = new List<Square> { sq1, sq5, sq7 };` As I consider, author has the same objects - `sql1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your original code would work:

```
var test2NotInTest1 = List2.Where(l1 => !List1.Contains(l1));
```

Only catch here is `Square` seems to be a class, and `List.Contains` would need the implementation of `IEqualityComparer<Square>`, which would be internally called to compare the Square objects, check this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/iequalitycomparer)